# How to get source code of currently installed Linux or do I even need it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remastersys

I'm trying to make my own Linux distro based on Ubuntu (I will make `.iso` with Remastersys or similar), which I will hopefully put online for others to download.

Will I need to publish the source code and if so how would I do so?

EDIT: Another thought, don't know if this matters.  So basically what I have done is I started with a Ubuntu 13.10 install, and installed a bunch of programs.  The only thing I really modified was Unity desktop, otherwise the programs are the same as when I downloaded them.   Do I need to publish the Source Code and if so, how would I do so?  Thanks!

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  You should create a metapackage that will install the prerequisites + your modifications and skip all the problems above while offering your "really cool mods" and _not_ further fracturing the community.

Answer (score 1):

In short: respect the copyright claims on any code you're using. Some might require you to publish your code, some won't, so verify which code you're using and read up on the various licencing types.

Usually you can publish your code any way you like: as a download on a website, on a public repository like github, etc.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?  What info would I all put out there?

Comment: I really suggest you start reading up on the different licence models and their requirement. I can't give you better hints than that because to be honest you're really missing essential knowledge on how Open Source software works.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the files you are using are under the GPL - which is very likely, you would be expected to make the files available via FTP, and, for version 2 of the GPL supply it on disk if asked.  See [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DistributeWithSourceOnInternet).